# Comparison of growth of a polynomial and exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials, exponential-function

I have a polynomial $p$ of degree $k$, with positive coefficients and $\forall -1\leq x\leq 1$ $$p(x)\leq c^{(x+1)^2}$$ for some constant $c>1$. Can I conclude the above inequality holds for all positive reals? If not under what conditions this may hold?

Comment: Counterexample: $2^{10}\leftrightarrow 2^{(x+1)^2}$.

Comment: I am sorry, but it should hold for $x\leq 1$. Then can I conclude it holds for $x>1$?

Comment: Ooops, sorry, I meant $x^{10}\leftrightarrow 2^{(x+1)^2}$.